# Error in DataLoader iteration using libtorch on windows

Tags: libtorch

## Question Description

I want to load the MNIST dataset with the following code：

```
auto dataset = torch::data::datasets::MNIST("./data/MNIST/raw")
        .map(torch::data::transforms::Stack<>());

auto data_loader = torch::data::make_data_loader(dataset, torch::data::DataLoaderOptions(512).workers(0));
```

But when I iterate through it with the following code, an exception is thrown

```
for (auto& batch : *data_loader){...}
```

## Debug

I found that just accessing the address corresponding to the iterator causes an error：

```
auto it = data_loader->begin();
auto batch = *it; //error
```

## Exception

The location of the exception thrown is here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YfHl.jpg)

## Environment

- win10
- vs2019
- libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-debug-1.12.1+cu113

It works fine on linux，how do I solve this problem?

Comment: What exception is thrown ? What error message do you get ?

Comment: I added exception screenshots and I found that pytorch with 1.8.2 works in windows.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem too, and when I switch to release package（libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-1.12.1+cu113）it works.